# Does multicollinearity affect EDA?

Tags: classification, multicollinearity, exploratory-data-analysis, churn

I have been working on a dataset pertaining to ***'churn analysis'.*** I have been trying to demonstrate ***whether the customers that are being charged more are also the ones that churn more or not.*** My dataset consists of as many as ***21 variables*** and has more than ***3.3K records.*** There are 4 columns that refer to the charges that are being imposed on the customers, separately for day, evening, night, and international. ***85% of the dataset is classified into 'False' category,*** i.e. the customers that did not churn, and the ***rest into its 'True'*** counterpart. I analyzed the effect of higher charges simply by ***plotting the PDFs*** (employed Histograms too but that obviously wasn't a good choice considering the imbalanced dataset that I have). Then I added the corresponding records in all these 4 variables and made one single variable for the total charges. Following is what I found out (of course on a sample);

[image]

However, I'm now thinking ***whether multicollinearity might have influenced such a trend that I depicted or not?*** I also want to know whether I need to take into consideration the other variables in the dataset or not? If yes, then in *what ways,* use *what techniques,* *find out what using them,* and most importantly, *why?*

Below is a glimpse of the dataset that I have been working on;

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can seek a model `churn ~ number_of_charges + international_plan + ...` and include any number of predictors.  Each predictor will increase or decrease the probability of churn.  Churn is a logical variable, so it would be a classification model or a logistic regression.

You would have to address multicollinearity and overfitting somehow, with possibly regularized regression.  For example `cv.glmnet(x, y, family = "binomial")` or `train(formula, data, method = "glmnet", family = "binomial")`.

I can anticipate a challenge: the customers that didn't churn might have a longer history and have accumulated more charges, etc.  This could confound your results unless you can find a way to address.

Recommend also you think about those histograms.  If you're scaling them somehow to plot two histograms on the same plot, it may be problematic to make a statement about the probability.  The height of a histogram or a pdf is not the same as probability.

Comment: Thank you @Arthur but the question that I have been working upon is simple; "whether the customers that are being charged more are also the ones that churn more or not". And the question that I asked too was pretty straightforward; "whether multicollinearity might have influenced such a trend that I depicted or not?" Alongside some supplementary questions. I did not get the answer to either of these. Could you please elaborate on my questions, perhaps you might have misinterpreted my questions earlier :)

Comment: My answer is "yes."  It's my opinion that in order to do an EDA with multiple variables, you should fit a simple model.  A model is the only way to understand the simultaneous action of a variety of predictor variables.  Plots and correlation coefficients only test pairwise relationships.